# How do I login with (PDO_SQLSRV) Code provided by microsoft, to access AdventureWorks Production table?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to create test application for some project with Sql Server AdventureWorks Production Table with code(Example Application (PDO_SQLSRV)) provided by microsoft,but when I run this code, the second 2 code or error pop's up...

```php
{<?php
$serverName  = "OSQSQSql\SQLEXPRESS";
/*Connect using Windows Authentication.*/
try
{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=AdventureWorks2017", "", "");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die( print_r($e->getMessage() ) );
```

I instead got this response 
[2]

````
   { setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); } catch(Exception $e) { die( print_r($e->getMessage() ) ); } if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])) { switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ) { /* Get AdventureWorks products by querying against the product name*/ case 'getproducts': try { $params = array($_POST['query']); $tsql = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Color, Size, ListPrice FROM Production.Product WHERE Name LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND ListPrice > 0.0"; $getProducts = $conn->prepare($tsql); $getProducts->execute($params); $products = $getProducts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $productsCount = count($products); if($productsCount > 0) { BeginProductsTable($productCount); foreach( $products as $row ) { PopulateProductsTable( $row ); } EndProductsTable(); } else { DisplayNoProductsMsg(); } } catch(Exception $e) { die(print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); } GetSeachTerms( !null ); break; /* Get reviews for a specified productID.*/ case 'getreview': GetPicture($_GET['productid'] ); break; /* Write a review for a specified productID.*/ case 'writereview': DisplayWriteReviewForm( $_POST['productid'] ); break; /* Submit a review to the database.*/ case 'submitreview': try { $tsql = "INSERT INTO Production.ProductReview (ProductID, ReviewerName, ReviewDate, EmailAddress, Rating, Comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; $params = array(&$_POST['procductid'], &$_POST['name'], date("Y-m-d"), &$_POST['email'], &$_POST['rating'], &$_POST['comments']); $insertReview = $conn->prepare($tsql); $insertReview->execute($params); } catch(Exception $e) { die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); } GetSeachTerms( true ); GetReviews( $conn, $_POST['productid'] ); break; /* Display form for uploading a picture.*/ case 'displayuploadpictureform': try { $tsql = "SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE ProductID = ?"; $getName = $conn->prepare($tsql); $getName->execute(array($_GET['productid'])); $name = $getName->fetchColumn(0); } catch(Exception $e) { die(print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); } DisplayUploadPictureForm( $_GET['procductid, $name ); break; /* Upload a new picturefor the selected product.*/ case 'uploadpicture'; try { $tsql = "INSERT INTO Production.ProductPhoto (LargePhoto) VALUES (?)"; $uploadPic = $conn->prepare($tsql); $fileStream = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r"); $uploadPic->bindParam(1, $fileStream, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY); $uploadPic->execute(); /* Get the first field - the identity from INSERT - so we can associate it with the product ID. */ $photoID = $conn->lastInsertid(); $tsql = "UPDATE Production.ProductProductPhoto SET ProductPhotoID = ? WHERE ProductID = ?"; $associateids->execute(array($photoID, $_POST['productid'])); } catch(Exception $e) { die(print_r($e->getMessage())); } GetPicture( $_POST['productid']); DisplayWriteReviewButton( $_POST['productid'] ); GetSeachTerms (!null); break; }//End Switch } else { GetSeachTerms( !null ); } function GetPicture( $productID ); { echo ""; echo ""; } function GetReviews( $conn, $producID ) { try { $tsql = "SELECT ReviewerName, CONVERT(verchar(32), ReviewDate, 107, AS [ReviewDate], Rating, Comments FROM ProductID = ? ORDER BY ReviewDate DESC"; $getReviews = $conn->prepare( $tsql); $getReviews->execute(array($productID)); $review = $getReviews->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); $reviewCount = count($reviews); if($reviewCount > 0 ) { foreach($reviews as $row) { $name = $row[0]; $date = $row[1]; $rating = $row[2]; $comments = $row[3]; DisplayReview( $productID, $name, $date, $rating, $comments ); } } else { DisplayNoReviewMsg(); } } catch(Exception $e) { die(print_r($e->getMessage())); } DisplayWriteReviewButton( $producID ); GetSearchTerms(!null); } /*** Presentation and Utility Functions ***/ function BeginProductsTable($rowCount) { /* Display the beginning of the search result table. */ $headings = array("Product ID" , "Product Name", "Color", "Size", "Price"); echo "}```
````

Please what am I doing wrong here, any suggestion,what is the right test code for creating Example Application with PDO_SQLSRV?

Comment: Can you rewrite your question to follow this guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? You include the code as snippets instead of images, and try to include the relevant part only.

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual code, not images of code (see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) for all the reasons why images of code are invalid). Also, please only include relevant code - the images you linked to look fairly extensive (with over 300 lines of code apiece), and I don't think all of it is needed.

Comment: Also, rather than just an image of the web page showing a bunch of error text, I suggest extracting that error text and including it specifically in your question, as formatted text. Otherwise, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: Thank you,I have edited the question and removed some code lines to make easily readable..please am looking forward for any suggestions ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that,I created folder in the root file and add the file in that folder like this `SqlApp/adventureworks_demo.php`,
I resolve the issue by removing the file from the folder and put the file directly to xampp root/`adventureworks_demo.php` like this as directedby Microsoft..

So dont put the file in your newly create folder,just save the file directly to the root file...

Comment: You can actually edit your answer & question. Please do not post multiple answers . Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I finally finding out what went wrong,,after XAMPP APACHE was installed in my OS,,my Sql Server Express Edition `server name` changes automatically without my notice from

ATLANTA\SQLEXPRESS to `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`it adopted my `local server`and drop the formal 
ATLANTA I was using..

So instead of `ATLANTA\SQLEXPRESS`that I was using to access my database before XAMPP APACHE installation,Its now `localhost\sqlexpress`becuase the XAMPP and SQL EXPRESS Edition in my OS is using the same SERVER